# Unique values but how to prevent with spelling mistakes - Odoo

Tags: python, orm, odoo, unique

I can use _sql_constraints as mentioned below to prevent duplicates but when user enter like:

Bakery

bakery

bakry

etc...

how i can prevent user to NOT enter this type of value?

```
> _sql_constraints = [
> 
>     ('categoryname_unique',
> 
>      'unique(name)',
> 
>      'each category should be unique'),
> 
> ]
```

Comment: Very interesting question and i don't see why to close it for duplicate, because the answers should focus on "how to solve it by using Odoo framework/API".

Comment: @CZoellner thanks for your favorable reply, seeking for same in Odoo forum, may be some kind of third party module help. hope for a solution :)

Comment: You could handle it with onchanges or Odoo's own constraint possibility. I have some ideas but no time to write good answers right now :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at least i can avoid duplication with same spelling but in either case (case insensitive) using below code (thanks to odoo forum - @Neha Sharma-Kanak)

```
@api.constrains('name')
def _check_unique_brand(self):
    brand_ids = self.search([]) - self

    value = [x.name.lower() for x in brand_ids]

    if self.name and self.name.lower() in value:
        raise ValidationError(_('The Brand Name is already Exist'))

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the **_sql_constraints** is not case sensitive so **Bakery** should be considered the same as **bakery**, therefore the record can't be created if it's the same attribute with different cases. Right ?

Comment: thanks for reply. but actual problem is "spelling mistakes" which should be prevented by system ... if possible. upper & lower case can be handled by odoo framework itself.

Comment: I don't think there is a framework that supports spell checking to do constraints on fields, you need a specific library that can analyze text and "know" if a word (bakry) is a duplicate 
mistype of (bakery) to do that for you. Check out this : https://pypi.org/project/pyspellchecker/

Comment: thanks to point me to "spellchecker", can we use it in Odoo framework? if yes, will you please guide or a link for guide to integrate in my custom Odoo module.

Comment: We can use any Python library in Odoo, it's just a matter of integration. You download the pip into your Odoo server and implement the functionality using the library. To get you started please take a look at this Flask implementation of pyspellchecker : https://towardsdatascience.com/spelling-rectification-app-using-textblob-pyspellchecker-cb3ad0504fc7, I believe the implementation inside Odoo could be achieved with a method decorated with @api.constraints('your.field') inside of which you're gonna implement pyspellchecker logic.

Comment: Also, check a python library called autocorrect, might be useful and easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, you can change it to `selection` field. Instead of User enter value, let's manager creates that values and User will select it from the list.